# UITapGestureRecognizer won't connect directly to assistant editor?

Tags: swift, ibaction, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to create a Button that utilizes a UITapGestureRecignizer to perform a segue. For some reason, when i try to control-drag from the  navigation panel to the assistant editor, it won't connect. I am using the following code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showChemistryDetailSegue" {

            let chemistryButton = sender!.view as! UIButton
            if let index = chemistryButtonArray.indexOf(chemistryButton){
                let chemistryDetailController = segue.destinationViewController as! ChemistryDetailViewController
                chemistryDetailController.chemistry = Chemistry(index: index)
            }

        }
    }
    @IBAction func showPlaylistDetail(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showChemistryDetailSegue", sender: sender)
    }

}
```

I am trying to connect the UITapGestures(there are 2) to the following block of code:

```
@IBAction func showPlaylistDetail(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showChemistryDetailSegue", sender: sender)
    }
```

I am wondering if there is a way to fix this.

Any suggestions or input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently figured out the answer. It was actually a really easy. I just connected the ViewController to the class I was trying to connect the UITapGestureReconizer to. Can't believe I didn't spot this simple error!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `sender` to `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

If that doesn't work, another thing you can do is just write it out programmatically.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "showPlaylistDetail:") 
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

@IBAction func showPlaylistDetail(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showChemistryDetailSegue", sender: sender)
}
```